# Check if you can’t change channel name

Tags: discord.js

I have a bot command to change the channel name. I know that you can only change the channel name through discord.js 2 times every 10 minutes. I want to send a message when it”s rate limited, but every time I do the command it doesn’t send anything.

```js
message.channel.setName("Name").then(() => message.reply("Changed name")).catch(() => message.reply("I am being rate limited"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure but if you hit the rate limit, does it even throw an error or is it just not executing the action?

Comment: It doesn’t execute the action

Comment: Well, if no error is thrown, it won't call the `.catch()` function

Comment: You could try (and again, I'm not sure if it works) checking the **promise**, the function `setName()` returns. Maybe the promise gets rejected and if so, you can create an **if-statement** and check for the promise result. If it's rejected, you can call ``message.channel.send("Rate limit")`

Comment: If you know what I mean

Comment: I think I figured it out, ```const channel = await message.channel.setName("Name");``` I tried this but then it doesn’t execute the rest of the code. I left it running but when I wasn’t rate limited anymore, that’s when it executed the rest of the code. So I think that .setName() doesn’t reject the Promise when it’s rate limited, it just keeps it pending. Do you have any fixes for that?

Comment: Not right now because I'm still at work, maybe I'll find something later

Comment: [This](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#exceeding-a-rate-limit) says you would get a 429 error if you get ratelimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a ratelimit you can use the [Client#rateLimit](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-rateLimit) event which returns a [RateLimitData](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RateLimitData) object.

```js
client.on('rateLimit', data => {
   console.error('Rate Limit Hit!');
   console.log(data);
});
```